# How to prevent duplicate record on run time

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code cause double record...
i checked my insert code for all tables and it works fine...

and this is insert code:

```
        StoreDO store = new StoreDO();
        List<BrandDO> brandList = new BrandBL().SelectBrands();
        StoreBL storeBL = new StoreBL();

        store.StoreName = txtStoreName.Text;
        store.StorePhone = txtStorePhone.Text;
        store.StoreAddress = txtStoreAddress.Text;
        store.CityID = int.Parse(ddlCity.SelectedValue);
        store.CountyID = int.Parse(ddlCounty.SelectedValue);
        store.IsActive = chkIsActive.Checked;
        int storeID = storeBL.InsertStore(store);
        ContentPlaceHolder contentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
        for (int i = 0; i < brandList.Count; i++) {
            string brandName = brandList[i].BrandName.ToString() + brandList[i].BrandID.ToString();
            StoreBrandBL storeBrandBL = new StoreBrandBL();
            CheckBox chkBrand = (CheckBox)contentPlaceHolder.FindControl(brandName);
            if (chkBrand != null) {
                if (chkBrand.Checked) {
                    StoreBrandDO storeBrandDO = new StoreBrandDO();
                    storeBrandDO.StoreID = storeID;
                    storeBrandDO.BrandID = brandList[i].BrandID;
                    storeBrandDO.IsActive = true;
                    storeBrandBL.InsertStoreBrand(storeBrandDO);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can prevent double records by using constraints on table columns.

Comment: It would help if you also show the DDL for the tables in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicating rows in your database should be avoided in the code and protected against in the database.

As `hwcverwe` said you can use table constraints but you should also try to set the primary key correctly for each table.

If you are using surrogate keys on all tables (such as the `StoreID` and `BrandID` I see in your code) then you will have to use unique table constraints to prevent duplicate data. Configuring your database correctly will also show up the problem areas in your code as the database will throw an exception when an insert fails.

**EDIT:** In response to your comment your question title is incorrect if you are asking about CheckBox controls.

Looking at the code it appears you are trying to find a checkbox control in a `ContentPlaceholder` but you do not show the code which creates the checkboxes.

Comment: i saw real problem a few minutes ago.. i cannot get chkboxes after i added null control insert is not happening... how i can access them... its not db or insert code ...

Comment: @serim urhan: I have added to my answer in response to your comment

Comment: i fix chkbox problem thank you so much but my double record problem continues what should i do

Comment: @serim urhan: Are you storing the data in a SQL database or some other data store? If SQL, which database server are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, SQLite etc.) and can you post the table structure you are using?

Comment: @serim urhan: great, what was your solution?

Comment: @tony it wasa my dll im getting last inserted id from database by using select @@identity by using excutescalar but i executed it after executenonquery that means i saw it after your dll warning thank you, its was me really sorry wasting your time